# Make .destop for ZSH such that it launches zsh and remains without transfering to .desktop of gnome-terminal?

Tags: bash, gnome-terminal, .desktop, zsh, desktop-icons

My `zsh.desktop` placed in `/home/user/.local/share/applications` acts as follows :

It opens fine when I double-click and execute, but after a few seconds the custom icon I set for `zsh.desktop` launcher disappears from launcher and the default icon for `gnome-terminal.desktop` located at `/usr/share/applications` appears instead and in case a `gnome-terminal` window was open previously they merge.

`zsh.desktop` contents :

```
[Desktop Entry]
X-AppInstall-Package=gnome-terminal-y
X-AppInstall-Section=main

Name=ZSH-Terminal
Comment=Use zsh in the command line
TryExec=zsh
Exec=zsh
Terminal=true
Icon=/home/lucifer/.oh-my-zsh/zsh.png
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
X-GNOME-SingleWindow=true
OnlyShowIn=GNOME;Unity;
Actions=New

Name[en_US]=ZSH-Terminal

[Desktop Action New]
Name=New Terminal
Exec=/usr/bin/zsh
```

**EDIT**

If `firefox stable` and `firefox nightly` are installed side by side, you see that when you execute either one it automatically  transfers into the `firefox` icon and this results in a common icon for both `nightly` and `stable` which is not good.

Something similar happens here for two different `.desktop`

**How I am solving this :**

There isn't a workable solution for segregating the two, what I did is to install `Tilix` from https://gnunn1.github.io/tilix-web/ (previously `Terminix`) and it runs as a separate process (PID) than `gnome-terminal` and then run `zsh` from there.

Comment: You're asking how to show different icons for same the command, but started with different arguments (plain gnome-terminal and gnome-terminal with zsh (here started automatically because `Terminal=true`). There are plenty of questions here asking the same for Java, for example, and other such commands which can be used to launch different programs. So yes, there's not just a possibility that this is a dupe, but it's highly likely to be one. I just can't be arsed to look one up...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way would be to run a separate Terminal Emulator (`Tilix`) since it will be using a separate `PID` and process and not the `gnome-terminal` one, then use `zsh` from there and you have a totally separate icon that works for `zsh`.

**`Tilix`:** https://gnunn1.github.io/tilix-web/

Answer (score 1):

Replace your `Exec` lines with the following :

```
Exec=gnome-terminal --class=zsh -e zsh
```

use :

```
Terminal=false
```

and add the line :

```
StartupWMClass=zsh
```

The file should look like this :

```
[Desktop Entry]
X-AppInstall-Package=gnome-terminal-y
X-AppInstall-Section=main

Name=ZSH-Terminal
Comment=Use zsh in the command line
TryExec=zsh
Exec=gnome-terminal --class=zsh -e zsh
Terminal=false
Icon=/home/lucifer/.oh-my-zsh/zsh.png
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
X-GNOME-SingleWindow=true
OnlyShowIn=GNOME;Unity;
Actions=New
StartupWMClass=zsh

Name[en_US]=ZSH-Terminal

[Desktop Action New]
Name=New Terminal
Exec=gnome-terminal --class=zsh -e zsh
```